# How to Intercept into an iPhone having access to same Wifi

Tags: whatsapp

I would  like to know, If I have password of a wifi-router? and I know the MAC address and IP of Target Iphone using this wifi-router, can I get to contents of social media like WhatsApp chats?

Comment: You’ve asked a similar question. Please don’t do this. One is enough.

Answer (score 0):

No.

Most traffic these days use additional encryption. Things like facebook chat only use TLS between the server and client, whilst WhatsApp uses the [Signal protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_Protocol) for true end to end-encryption. You can not get access to this by intercepting the traffic at the IP layer.